# Using separated Intent for each fragmented tabs in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I'm trying to create tabs with swipe view using fragment. I found a solution but it provides a single dummy text layout for each tabs instead of using separated layout. I'd like to create three different classes with three different layouts and use them in tabs and if possible then using a custom background for each tabs (while selected/not selected). I can do all these things without fragment but using fragment it seems challenging.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);
            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your target you must use **ActionBarSherlock** library, and to call other fragments you should not need to use Intent,

I have written same kind of program few months ago to call different Fragments i used below code

```
 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        switch (arg0) {

        // Open FragmentTab1.java
        case 0:
            FragmentTab1 fragmenttab1 = new FragmentTab1();
            return fragmenttab1;

        // Open FragmentTab2.java
        case 1:
            FragmentTab2 fragmenttab2 = new FragmentTab2();
            return fragmenttab2;

        // Open FragmentTab3.java
        case 2:
            FragmentTab3 fragmenttab3 = new FragmentTab3();
            return fragmenttab3;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and to call show different - different layouts for each and every Fragment you should call different - different Fragments and also need to write XMLs too .....

**FragmentTab1.java :-**

```
public class FragmentTab1 extends SherlockFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the view from fragmenttab1.xml
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        setUserVisibleHint(true);
    }
  }
```

**fragment1.xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Your Layout Goes Here for Fragment1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

in a same way you have to write classes and xmls for all needed Fragments....

for more detailed information or to try out an example, use this :

```
  http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-actionbarsherlock-viewpager-tabs-tutorial/
```

Comment: thanks a lot for explaining clearly! it was really helpful! One more question, Can I customize the tabs background? @KL Amit Suri

Comment: @ProkashSarkar your welcome :) God Bless, yeah i suggest you to use image button to make your tabs smart

Answer (score 0):

in the following link that help you how to create Tab fragment in sperated intents:

[Tab Fragments](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-fragment-tabs-in-android/)