# After remove and add new actionbar tab, OnPageSelected not working properly

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using a ViewPager and actionbar tabs. I am adding four tabs and then populate in an array and remove one of them at start as it always show three tabs. At click on "Ask"
tab the "Home" tab will remove and add tab from array "Login". and "Ask" moves to first position Now every thing is fine but when i click on "Login" tab nothings happen and click on "Ask" it moves to fragment connected to "Login" tab.
Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity{

public static ActionBar actionbar;
static Context thisContext;
public static MyAdapter mAdapter;
public static ViewPager mPager;
public static String user_id = "";
Boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
public static ArrayList<Tab> motor_tabs = new ArrayList<ActionBar.Tab>();
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // construct the tabhost

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    thisContext = this;

    // setup action bar for tabs
    actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    //  actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);  --> Doing this after adding the tabs now for checking
    // actionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    }


    // code for enabling scrolling
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mAdapter.setActionBar(actionbar);
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    //mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);


    Tab tab1 = actionbar
                .newTab()
                .setText("Home")
                .setTabListener(
                        (com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.TabListener) new TabListener<android.support.v4.app.Fragment>(
                                this, 0 + "", mPager));
        motor_tabs.add(tab1);
        actionbar.addTab(tab1);

        Tab tab2 = actionbar
                .newTab()
                .setText("Ask")
                .setTabListener(
                        (com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.TabListener) new TabListener<android.support.v4.app.Fragment>(
                                this, 1 + "", mPager));
        motor_tabs.add(tab2);
        actionbar.addTab(tab2);

        Tab tab3 = actionbar
                .newTab()
                .setText("Login")
                .setTabListener(
                        (com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.TabListener) new TabListener<android.support.v4.app.Fragment>(
                                this, 2 + "", mPager));
        motor_tabs.add(tab3);
        actionbar.addTab(tab3);

        Tab tab4 = actionbar
                .newTab()
                .setText("About")
                .setTabListener(
                        (com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.TabListener) new TabListener<android.support.v4.app.Fragment>(
                                this, 3 + "", mPager));
        motor_tabs.add(tab4);
        actionbar.addTab(tab4);
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        //actionbar.removeTabAt(2);
        //actionbar.getTabAt(3).setTag(2);
        MainActivity.actionbar.removeTabAt(2);
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("ViewPager", "onPageSelected: " + arg0);
                if (arg0 == 1 && actionbar.getTabAt(1).getText().equals("AskRoz")){
                    MainActivity.actionbar.removeTabAt(0);
                    MainActivity.actionbar.addTab(MainActivity.motor_tabs.get(2), 1);

                    Globals.ismotorSports = false;
                    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                }
                actionbar.getTabAt(arg0).select();
            }

        });
}

private void enableEmbeddedTabs(Object actionBar) {
    try {
        Method setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod = actionBar.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setHasEmbeddedTabs", boolean.class);
        setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.setAccessible(true);
        setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.invoke(actionBar, true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("enableEmbeddedTabsException", "Error marking actionbar embedded", e);
    }
}


public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    ActionBar mActionBar;

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return MainActivity.actionbar.getTabCount();
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            if(Globals.ismotorSports){
                MotorSearchActivity motorsearch = new MotorSearchActivity();
                return motorsearch;
            }
            else{
                SearchActivity search = new SearchActivity();
                return search;
            }

        case 1:
            if(Globals.ismotorSports){
                SearchActivity search = new SearchActivity();
                return search;
            }
            else{
                LoginFragment login = LoginFragment.newInstance(false);
                //LoginFragment login = new LoginFragment();
                return login;
            }

        case 2:
            AboutActivity about = new AboutActivity();
            return about;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
    public void setActionBar(ActionBar bar) {
        mActionBar = bar;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use complicated ways to call your ***Fragments***, try to use simple solution, i am writing below for you, change name of fragments as needed:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        switch (arg0) {

        // Open FragmentTab1.java
        case 0:
            FragmentTab1 fragmenttab1 = new FragmentTab1();
            return fragmenttab1;

        // Open FragmentTab2.java
        case 1:
            FragmentTab2 fragmenttab2 = new FragmentTab2();
            return fragmenttab2;

        // Open FragmentTab3.java
        case 2:
            FragmentTab3 fragmenttab3 = new FragmentTab3();
            return fragmenttab3;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

for **more see this**:

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922080/using-separated-intent-for-each-fragmented-tabs-in-android
```

Comment: Sorry my fault. Error was somewhere else and i'm looking for it here.
but any way thanks for help